# USB card reader

Tags: 11.10, drivers, usb, source-code, sd-card

I am using a Gear Head USB card reader on Ubuntu 11.1 and it works great. The model number of the device is CR3000MSD. I am looking for some working source code in any language really that will allow me to access the device at the hardware level. In other words C++ library, open source driver etc? I know there must be source code since the device is working perfectly on Ubuntu 11.1. The reason I started using Ubuntu is so I can pick a part code for these types of devices. Does anyone know where I can find some working code for this device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find some source code written by Michel Machado that did what I needed with the SD card. I was going to write something a little bit more at the hardware level but it is not going to be necessary this time.

The program I found is called [F3](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/) and is the Linux equivalent to H2TestW for Windows. I found both applications to work very well.